# Tool functions for chars

Tags: c, char

I want to handle some char variables and would like to get a list of some functions that can do these tasks when it comes to handling chars.

- Getting first characters of a char (var_name[1] doesnt seem to work)
- Getting last characters of a char
- Checking for char1 matches with char2 ( eg if "unicorn" matches words with "bicycle"

I am pretty sure some of these methods exist in libraries such as stdio.h or so but google isnt my friend.

EDIT:My 3rd question means not direct match with strcmp but single character match(eg if "hey" and "hello") have e as common letter.

Comment: Indices are 0-based, and `char` is a single character. Did you mean `char*`?

Comment: A variable of type `char` only holds a single character -- there's no first and last. Do you mean a string, i.e. `char[]` or `char*`?

Comment: yes Caleb,i mean both you mentioned.

Comment: Using my favorite search engine on "C char functions" gave me lots of interesting results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Use `var_name[0]` to get first character (array indexes run from `0` to `N - 1`, where `N` is the number of elements in the array).
- Use `var_name[strlen(var_name) - 1]` to get the last character.
- Use [`strcmp()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/) to compare two `char` strings.

EDIT:

To search for character in a string you can use [`strchr`()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strchr/):

```
if (strchr("hello", 'e') && strchr("hey", 'e'))
{
}
```

There is also [`strpbrk()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strpbrk/) function that would indicate if two strings have any common characters:

```
if (strpbrk("hello", "hey"))
{
}
```

<sub>Assuming you mean a `char[]`, and not a `char` which is a single character.</sub>

Comment: dammit, I was a little slow :)

Comment: Thank you,thats a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. C uses 0-based indexing, var_name[0] gives you the first char.
2. strlen() gives you the length of the string, which together with my answer to 1. means
   char lastchar = var_name[strlen(var_name)-1];  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strlen/
3. strcmp(var_name1, var_name2) == 0. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcmp/

Comment: Clever way of getting the last character there.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the string functions in the [C runtime library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling).  These are defined in string.h, not stdio.h.

But your list of problems is simple:

var_name[0] works perfectly well for accessing the first char in an array.  var_name[ 1] doesn't work because arrays in C are zero-based.

The last char in an array is:

```
char c;
c = var_name[strlen(var_name)-1];
```

Testing for equality is simple:

```
if (var_name[0] == var_name[1])
   ; // they match
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.var_name[1] was just an example of accessing a single character not the first one(which is 0).

Answer (score 0):

> I am pretty sure some of these methods exist in libraries such as
>   stdio.h or so but google isnt my friend.

The string functions in the C standard library (libc) are described in the header file . If you're on a unix-ish machine, try typing `man 3 string` at a command line. You can then use the `man` program again to get more information about specific functions, e.g. `man 3 strlen`. (The '3' just tells `man` to look in "section 3", which describes the C standard library functions.)

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ strings are zero indexed. The memory you need to hold a particular length string has to be at least the string length and one character for the string terminator \0. So, the first character is array[0].

As @Carey Gregory said, the basic string handling functions are in string.h. But these are only primitives for handling strings. C is a low level enough language, that you have an opportunity to build up your own string handling library based on the functions in string.h.

On example might be that you want to pass a string pointer to a function and also the length of the buffer holding that sane string, not just the string length itself.